# Check whether a controller's method was called from a real request or from a controller spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have a model `Position` with a field `started_at` and `ended_at`, both of which are `datetime` fields. Because the date part of both have to be the same, I have a `datetime_select` form field for `started_at` but only a `time_select ignore_date: true` for `ended_at`. In the `create` method I'd like to assign the date values of `started_at` to `ended_at` like this:

```
params[:position]["ended_at(1i)"] = params[:position]["started_at(1i)"]
params[:position]["ended_at(2i)"] = params[:position]["started_at(2i)"]
params[:position]["ended_at(3i)"] = params[:position]["started_at(3i)"]
```

But this broke my controller specs, because there I assign the values directly:

```
describe "POST create" do
  describe "with valid params" do
    it "creates a new Position" do
      expect {
        post :create, {:position => valid_attributes}, valid_session
      }.to change(Position, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

So I ended up with this, but I'm not sure whether it is a reasonable fix:

```
if params[:position]["ended_at(1i)"].nil? and not params[:position]["started_at(1i)"].nil? # We have to check this because in the controller specs we assign the params directly (not in this crazy xxx_at(yi) form for dates), so by checking this we know that the data was sent through the form
  params[:position]["ended_at(1i)"] = params[:position]["started_at(1i)"]
  params[:position]["ended_at(2i)"] = params[:position]["started_at(2i)"]
  params[:position]["ended_at(3i)"] = params[:position]["started_at(3i)"]
end
```

Maybe there's a better solution? Thanks for your opinions.

Comment: If you're testing the controller, doesn't it make sense to test using the actual parameters that are going to be sent in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the controller is expecting the attributes in a specific format, the spec should supply them in that format. Adjust `valid_attributes` so that it separates the date and time elements in the same way that the form does, and the spec should pass.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to have separate columns for the date and time for the end date/time?

Then have something like:

**models/position.rb**

```
before_create :set_end_date

def set_end_date
  self[:end_date] = self[:started_at].to_date
end
```

**spec/controllers/position_controller_spec.rb**

```
describe "POST Create" do
  describe "with valid attr" do
     it "should create a new Position" do
       lambda do
         post :create, position: valid_attributes, valid_session
       end.should change(Position, :count).by(1)
     end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check `Rails.env.test?`